# Vaadin AceEditor focus issues

Tags: focus, vaadin, ace-editor, vaadin7, valuechangelistener

I have recently downloaded the AceEditor Add-On for Vaadin (http://vaadin.com/addon/aceeditor) and i have a few issues with it, i hope you can help me out!

1. The first issue is that the ValueChangeListener of the AceEditor is called in every typing event (just like the TextChangeListener), and **NOT** just when the area looses focus, like in a regular TextArea.
   I need a listener that would be called only when the AceEditor looses focus. i have also tried to add a BlurListener to this component, but it is also not working... any suggestions?...
2. The second issue is also related - when i press the TAB key inside the AceEditor, it just adds a TAB to the text instead of changing focus. 
   I've tried adding a shortcutListener with KeyCode.TAB but it didnt work... i also tried adding a shortcutListener to the whole Panel. didnt work either.  any suggestions about that?...

Thank you!!

Comment: I suggest you contact the add-on developer directly. Behind your link is another link to the issue tracker. That would be a good place. There is a merge a day ago that fixes something regarding blur events which might fix your issues as well.

Comment: Hi, I already tried asking him on the Add-On page, but didn't want to open an issue for that, but maybe i should do that.
Thanks for your reply! i will try the new merge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so mucn @Jens Jansson !
The new merge worked!